# Protect a range when a case is closed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that it's used by a lot of people.
Every line is like a case.
I want to - whenever the case is closed by the user - automatically protect its row so no one will be able to modify it.

The logical function will be like this for first case (line 2)

`=IF (A2 and B2 and C2 is not blank or empty, and K2 is "done")` -> protect range A2:K2 so that the only one able to modify it is the spreadsheet owner
Otherwise, leave it that way

I know this can't be done by a formula on the sheet, but it can be done by a script, so, can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

Utilizing the [Protection Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) you can protect your selected ranges. You just need to handle whatever logic you need to determine if the range needs protection or not.

Example code from the above page:

```
 // Protect range A1:B10, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var range = ss.getRange('A1:B10');
 var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');

 // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
 // permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.
 var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
 protection.addEditor(me);
 protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
 if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
   protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
```

Comment: You should also mention that this requires the calling code to have the correct script `AuthMode`. Otherwise it will throw an error (i.e. if someone tried to use the simple trigger `onEdit` to run your code)